# Simple Dynamic Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I know it's a dumb question but I hope someone can help me here:

```
int size = 5;
int* newarray = new int[size];
```

This Array won't work. It will have

```
newarray[1] = very big minus number;
```

And not an array of Size 5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think the values of an array should be initialized to? Hint: they aren't initialized.

Comment: `newarray` is uninitialized

Comment: You've *declared* the array, but you haven't *initialized* any of the values.

Comment: Sidenote: use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of raw arrays and pointers

Comment: @UnholySheep since it clearly is a learning exercise, naked pointers are fine here.

Answer (score 2):

It would not be a dump question if it would not be for vague '*won't work*' statement. You should be very specific when you describe the problem.

In your particular case, the array 'works'. But the individual elements of the array are not initialized with this statement. This is by design. If you want them to be initialized to 0, you can use

```
int* newarray = new int[size]();
```

If you want it initialized to anything else, you will have to write code to initialize every member to desired value.

Comment: it does not matter how big size is, it will only have the real-size of one ( = newnumber[1])

Comment: @V.Kirsch What makes you think so?

Comment: @V.Kirsch -- *it does not matter how big size is, it will only have the real-size of one* -- What does "real size" mean?   Are you saying that C++ is all wrong, and when you allocate `size` integers, you're being lied to?

Comment: int main()
{
int m_Size;
int* m_Array;

cin >> m_Size;
m_Array = new (nothrow) int[m_Size];
}

Will always just have 1 Container. It does not matter how high m_Size is.

So it will always be
m_Array[0] = -something;

Comment: @V.Kirsch what do you expect in `m_Array[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

In C++, when you dynamically initialize an array using `new` keyword like:

```
1. int *array = new int[size]
2. int *array = new int[size]()
```

(1) allocates a portion of memory for that particular type and size in the memory, followed by default initialization (may or may not be zero). While (2) will initialize everything to 0.
However since memory allocation is contagious, you can still access elements outside provided size but will have some garbage value. It's certainly not recommended to go outside of allocated size, since it may lead to unexpected behavior.
So whenever you see a negative value,  you are probably going out of the scope of allocated area.